# Django Project - 'urlpatterns' = (syntax error - cannot assign to literal)....Please advise?

Tags: django, url

**Django Project** - `'urlpatterns'` = (syntax error - cannot assign to literal)....Please advise?

Comment: It is `urlpattterns = ...`, not `'urlpatterns' = ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign to a variable, you use an *identifier*, not a string literal, you thus construct the `urlpatterns` with:

```
# ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ no string identifier
urlpatterns = [
    # …
]
```